# How to key press "CTRL + S " in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i have a situation where a pdf file is opened in a browser. Now i need to save the file to my desktop.
I think the only possibility to save the file is to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>.

Now how do I send the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> action to my browser.

I need to do this in Selenium Webdriver using c#.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to test here. Why would you need to save it to the desktop in a test - isn't that really just testing the browser's save functionality rather than your app?

Comment: i need to verify the file name with which it is getting saved and then reopen the saved file and few more operations.

Comment: I would personally just validate that the headers are what you expect them to be - it'll be a lot cleaner than messing around with the desktop file system (and cleaning up the files afterwards).

Comment: Looking at the documentation, you might be able to use Actions.KeyDown and Actions.SendKeys, but then you'd need to handle the dialog box as well...

Comment: i tried these key Down of ctrl key and then sendkeys of s key but it does not seem to work... kept trying for several hours.. dint know if it was error in my side or if that is not possible at all

Comment: If you've tried things already, you should have included that in the question, to avoid wasting time going over existing ground.

Answer (score 0):

You must also use **WshShell.SendKeys** method of COM component *C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wshom.ocx* (ProgID **WScript.Shell**) to send keys to browsers (the apis provided with Selenium WebDriver do not work). Steps:

- *Right click project file --> Add --> Com Reference --> Browse --> Select C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wshom.ocx*. You should be seeing in Dependencies/COM node in Visual Studio **Interop.IWshRuntimeLibrary**. Click on it and change "*Embed Interop Types*" from Yes to No (if you use Net Core).

  [image: Interop.IWshRuntimeLibrary]
- Read the [msdn documentation for SendKeys](https://qa.social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5169.vbscript-sendkeys-method.aspx), I use then the following code to save a web page as a single html file with Edge/ChromeDriver, probably it should work also for saving a PDF file:

```csharp
        var wshShell = new WshShellClass();
        var filename = "file.mhtml";

        wshShell.SendKeys("^s"); // send CTRL + s
        Thread.Sleep(1000);  // wait 1 sec to open the save dialog box

        // send alt+n, enter filename
        wshShell.SendKeys($"%n{filename}");
        Thread.Sleep(20);
        // send alt+v, page down, page up (to select single mhtml), press enter twice
        wshShell.SendKeys($"%v");
        Thread.Sleep(20);
        wshShell.SendKeys($"{{DOWN}}");
        Thread.Sleep(20);
        wshShell.SendKeys($"{{UP}}");
        Thread.Sleep(20);
        wshShell.SendKeys($"~~");

        Thread.Sleep(3000);   // wait 3 seconds to finish the saving from Chrome
```